# How is it working? Please explain to me line by line

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, reverse

//#~------Reverse An Array--------~#\
How is it working? Please explain to me line by line.

```
    var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++){
    var temp = arr[i]
    arr[i] = arr[arr.length - 1 - i]
    arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = temp
    }
    console.log(arr)
```

Comment: What do you not understand? it reads one side of the array. It counts back on the other side the same amount and gets that number, they swap the positions until it reaches halfway.

Comment: Thank you sir for your response. I'm new to javascript and learning this language.  sir, I do not understand How's the loop going? 
please explain me like this-

`1st pass: i=0 and arr.length = 6; // 0<6 true`
`2nd pass: i=1 and arr.length = 5; // 1<5 true`
`3rd pass: i=2 and arr.length = 4; // 2<4 true`
`4th pass: i=3 and arr.length = 3; // 3<3 false and it does not execute`

Comment: @forhad No Problem. I also hope to get my answers like this. But remember repeated bad question will most likely to give you a question ban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Line 1` : Array Declaration.
`Line 2` : Then you run a loop for a half of the array.
`Line 3,4,5` : alternating the number like this shown below.[image]

`Line 6` : Print it in the console window.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how it works in the following snippet. The program swaps two outer numbers and continues to the center.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
  document.write(arr+"<br />");
  var temp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[arr.length - 1 - i];
  arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = temp;
};
document.write(arr);
```